# Swift: how do I concatenate a [[String]] to a [String] the right way?

Tags: ios, swift

There are new `Array` functions in swift - `map`, `reduce` etc.

I'd like to use these to concatenate a `[[String]]` to a `[String]` but I can't figure out how. (I'm assuming `map` or `reduce` would do what I want but could be wrong).

What is the best way to do what I need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use `reduce` for that, since you're basically going from an array of `T` down to `T`, it's just that `T = [String]`.

```
let stringArray = stringArrayArray.reduce([]) { $0 + $1 }
```

You can write it even more concisely by using operator shorthand instead of a closure:

```
let stringArray = stringArrayArray.reduce([], +)
```

And here's the full way to write it out, so you can see what's happening:

```
1: let stringArray = stringArrayArray.reduce([]) {
2:         (accumulated: [String], element: [String]) -> [String] in
3:         return accumulated + element
4:     }
```

In line 1, we provide an empty array for the initial value. Line 2 defines the arguments and return type of the closure: `accumulated` is the initial value in the first iteration, and the result of the previous iteration thereafter, while `element` is the current element of the source array. Line 3 simply adds the accumulated array with the current element to merge them together.

Comment: For performances, one might want `.reduce(into: []) { $0 += $1 }`